Getting crash in Play Store because Android RecyclerView
I'm using a Adapter and RecyclerView. I try to change the color of the first and last  item  in my RecyclerView
But I get this Crashe in play store  here my adapter class and main code
my RecyclerView in NestedScrollView I read some tips online and applied them but the crash is not gone
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
  at com.jodaland.example.TableAdapter.onBindViewHolder (TableAdapter.java:66)
  at com.jodaland.example.TableAdapter.onBindViewHolder (TableAdapter.java:17)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.java:7065)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder (RecyclerView.java:7107)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:6012)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:6279)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:6118)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:6114)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next (LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk (LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill (LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2 (RecyclerView.java:4134)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure (RecyclerView.java:3540)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:27131)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7951)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:27131)
  at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins (NestedScrollView.java:1792)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
  at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure (NestedScrollView.java:627)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:27131)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:995)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:27131)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure (ConstraintLayout.java:811)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:632)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:733)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem (BasicMeasure.java:160)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure (BasicMeasure.java:291)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem (ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure (ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:27131)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:27131)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7951)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:27131)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:27131)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7951)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:27131)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure (DecorView.java:1173)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:27131)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:4187)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:2936)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3204)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2618)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:9971)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1010)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:809)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:744)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:995)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8653)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TableAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        Modal m = this.modalList.get(position);

        if (holder.getItemViewType() == TYPE_HEAD) {

            int colorGreen = ContextCompat.getColor(holder.Time.getContext(),R.color.Green);
            holder.Time.setBackgroundColor(colorGreen);
            holder.Time.setText(m.getTime());

            int colorGray = ContextCompat.getColor(holder.Money.getContext(),R.color.Gray);
            holder.Money.setBackgroundColor(colorGray);
            holder.Money.setText(m.getMoney());

            int colorOchre = ContextCompat.getColor(holder.profit.getContext(),R.color.Ochre);
            holder.profit.setBackgroundColor(colorOchre);
            holder.profit.setText(m.getprofit());

            int colorBlue = ContextCompat.getColor(holder.Sum.getContext(),R.color.Blue);
            holder.Sum.setBackgroundColor(colorBlue);
            holder.Sum.setText(m.getSum());
        }else {
  //line 66      holder.Time.setText(m.getTime());
                 holder.Money.setText(m.getMoney());
                 holder.profit.setText(m.getprofit());
                 holder.Sum.setText(m.getSum());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int a;
        if (modalList != null && !modalList.isEmpty()) {
            a = modalList.size();
        } else {
            a = 0;
        }
        return a;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0 || position == modalList.size()-1 )
            return TYPE_HEAD;
        return TYPE_LIST;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView Time;
        public TextView Money;
        public TextView profit;
        public TextView Sum;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_time);
            Money = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_money);
            profit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_profit);
            Sum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_sum);
        }
    }
}

Please help and provide some advice

Maybe you can attach the xml file to make easy in review your code. :)

Either holder.Time is null, or m is null.  You can check which it is with a breakpoint.  If it's holder.Time, either your xml file doesn't have that view or your onCreateViewHolder is wrong.  If it's m, then your list has a null element and you need to either prevent or check for that.
